# display data in listview from database in asynctask by getting response from server in array

Tags: android

I want to display some data in a listview from database using asynctask.
I want that firstly user inputs some data and on submit button click in doinbackground in asynctask, database checks for result like login something and from there details or response comes from database in the form of array. Now i want that details to be displayed in a listview.

I want the details to be displayed in another activity.

Here is my code:

public class Address extends AppCompatActivity{

```
 Button showRest;
 Toolbar toolbar;
 String city,location;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.address);


    final Spinner spinnercity = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cityname);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =           ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.city_name, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnercity.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinnercity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             city = spinnercity.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });


    final Spinner spinnerlocation = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.citylocation);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterloc = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.city_location, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapterloc.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerlocation.setAdapter(adapterloc);

    spinnerlocation.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            location = spinnerlocation.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_invite);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent mainpage = new Intent(Address.this,Open.class);
            startActivity(mainpage);
        }
    });

    showRest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnshow_rest);
    showRest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             checkInto(city,location);
        }
    });


}

private void checkInto(final String city, String location) {

    class CheckAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private Dialog loadingDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Address.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String city = params[0];
            String location = params[1];
            InputStream is = null;
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", city));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location", location));
            String result = null;

            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                        RestConfig.DATA_URL);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            String s = result.trim();
            loadingDialog.dismiss();
            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                Toast.makeText(Address.this, "Succes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    CheckAsync la = new CheckAsync();
    la.execute(city, location);
}
```

}